# Узнать индекс самого большого элемента массива по значению. C#

Tags: c#

Мне нужно узнать индекс самого большого по значению элемента массива arr длиной в 10 элементов. Я это делаю так: сначала я создаю копию массива copy, затем сортирую его, а дальше узнаю индекс так:

```
arr[Array.IndexOf(arr, copy[9]);
```

Но отладчик выдаёт ошибку "Индекс находился вне границ массива". Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Проверьте длину copy, и что возвращает IndexOf. Вообще это задача на использование цикла for и оператора if

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно что вы делаете, но вам нужно написать простой цикл, который присвоил бы значение индекса какой либо переменной, если значение временной переменной меньше чем текущее значение в массиве.

```
uint[] data = new uint[10];

Random rnd = new Random();

for(uint i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine((data[i] = (uint)rnd.Next(0, 100)));
}

uint tmpValue = 0;
uint index = 0;

Console.WriteLine("--------");

for(uint i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    tmpValue = tmpValue < data[i] ? data[i] : tmpValue;
    index = tmpValue > data[i] ? index : i;
}

Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}, Value: {1}", index, tmpValue);
```

Результат:

```
71
48
35
63
91
4
64
5
60
33
--------
Index: 4, Value: 91
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй указывать не 9, а длину массива, синтаксис
имя_массива.Length

Comment: Нет, так не работает, ведь длина массива 10. Нет же такого элемента у нас, 9 максимум.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нельзя узнать что не так по одной лишь строчке кода.
2. Копировать и сортировать массив, чтобы найти максимальный элемент? А вы знаете толк в извращениях.
3. Вот вариант, который будет работать

   arr.IndexOf(arr.Max());

Comment: тогда уж `Array.IndexOf(input, input.Max());`